# why do void sort methods return the paramater changed?

Tags: java, sorting, methods

I have been writing various methods with return statements, but I recently was told to just leave the methods void and your parameter will be changed

simply

```
mergeSort(a);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

will print a sorted array a.

Why is this true? How does the parameter get changed without return.

I am used to scripting languages, maybe this is the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use an example. I find that the terminology only serves to confuse.

You have a string:
`String name = "Paul";`

You call `System.out.println("Name is: " + rename(name, "Frank"));`->
`Name is: Frank`
But `System.out.println("Name is: " + name);`->`Name is: Paul`.

This is because rename gets a *copy* of `name`. `name` is untouched. If you want to modify the original, rename should look like this:

```
void rename(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}
```

Remember, any time that you give a function an object, you give it a *copy* of that object. I am almost certain I have not made a mistake, but I'm booting up eclipse right now to double check that I am correct.

EDIT: I tested it in eclipse.

### Full Working Example

```
static String name = "Paul";

public static String rename(String originalName, String newName) {
    originalName = newName;
    return originalName;
}

public static void rename(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(rename(name, "Sally"));
    System.out.println(name); //name = "Paul"

    rename("Sally");
    System.out.println(name); //name = "Sally"
}
```

Output:

```
Sally
Paul
Sally
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. For more clarity, Should I think be using the original variable name, from main method in the final assignments?

Comment: @user1340048 I'm glad I could help! I'm not sure, but I think you're asking about variables with `final`. `final` only allows values to be set once. `final String name = "Paul"` would lock the value of `name` to `"Paul"`. You can also wait to set the value. `final String name` and later, `name = "Sally"` would lock it as "Sally".

Answer (score 0):

An array is a mutable object. If you have a reference to an array, you can modify it.

I've taken the example provided in a different response, and shown how it can be modified to use an array, whose contents can then be modified:

```
class Test
    {
    static final char[] name = "Paul".toCharArray();

    public static void main(String[] asArg)
        {
        System.out.println("name=" + new String(name));
        rename(name, "Mary");
        System.out.println("name=" + new String(name));
        }

    public static void rename(char[] name, String newName)
        {
        System.arraycopy(newName.toCharArray(), 0, name, 0, Math.min(name.length, newName.length()));
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
$ java Test
name=Paul
name=Mary
```

In the manner, passing a reference to an array is very similar to passing a "pointer to an array" in C, in that the method (function) that receives that reference (pointer) is then able to both access and modify the values stored in that array.

Answer (score -1):

There is an important distinction between call by value and call by name. Javascript is a call-by-value language - all parameters are passed as values. However, the value of a variable containing an object is a reference to that object; changing the contents of the object does not constitute changing the function parameter (strictly speaking). I.e. if you call `mergeSort(a)`, when it returns, the `a` is still the same `a`, pointing at the same memory location, but it will have different content.